# OCR: Exponent detection, super/subscripts(C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr

I have been able to recognize characters, such as `1`, `2`, `3`, ..., `n`.

I have been having trouble thinking of a way to detect that a certain number is the exponent of another.

For example, after running my program [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awLL1.png) should return `(5/6)^2`, but I can't figure a way or an idea to say that this number is an exponent.

Any suggestions? I am using openCV in c++.

Answer (score 0):

When detecting the characters, you will have their respective bounding boxes. There are some assumptions to be made, like knowing the approximate scale of characters, let's call it S - you could infer this from the size of all detected bounding boxes.

Based on this you could try the following:

1. for each detected bounding box (D_bbox), define a search range from the centre of the bounding box to ± 2 * S
2. in this search area, look for other bounding box centres (O_bbox), from the other detected characters

   3. for each centre found in the search region, compute the ratio between D_bbox and O_bbox. The exponent character size should be smaller than the number => D_bbox/O_bbox > 1.

I'd say it should be around 1.5 but this depends on font etc. Play with the values and see what you get.

some other heuristics that might help:

- D_bbox_centre_x < O_bbox_centre_x
- D_bbox_centre_y < O_bbox_centre_y

The number is always to the left of the exponent and it's centre is always lower on the page than the exponent's centre.

I wouldn't try to detect the parentheses because there can be instances in which you don't use them to write an exponent.